# Dropdown too long, how to add more columns?

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

One of the dropdowns on my main navigation has over 70 items on it so is so long that it goes off the screen, as seen in the image below:

[image]

How can I make it so they go across multiple columns so that the dropdown fits on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with some css trickery:

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

```
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HP85j/1463/